# How can i get custom field to apear on my wordpress admin area (post_type)

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I had an issue with WordPress posts_type , the custom fields which are normally at the bottom of each post page were missing.

At the top of your WordPress post page you will see a small grey box that says.. Screen Options. Click this option and then it will provide you with a drop down menu.

I ceck the custom field, it apears but after i Publish The page it disepear again..

I disable all the plugin but no sucess... the same...

How i register my custom post type...

```
/* ------------ Post Type Stiri -----------*/
register_post_type('stiri', array(  'label' => 'Stiri','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
'query_var' => true,'has_archive' => true,
'menu_position' => 5,'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields','category', 'post_tag',),
'labels' => array (
'name' => 'Stiri',
  'singular_name' => 'Stire',
  'menu_name' => 'Stiri',
  'add_new' => 'Add Stire',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Stire',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Stire',
  'new_item' => 'New Stire',
  'view' => 'View Stire',
  'view_item' => 'View Stire',
  'search_items' => 'Search Stiri',
  'not_found' => 'No Stiri Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Stiri Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Stire',
),) );

register_taxonomy("stire","stiri", array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Cat Stiri", 'show_ui' => true, 'query_var' => true, "singular_label" => "stire", "rewrite" => true , 'with_front' => true));
```

If annyone have a solution please post here

Comment: Are you using the built-in interface or have you built your own admin page for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the wrong hook for include the custom post type?
Do you init your CPT with the function `register_post_type()` on hook `init`?

But the settings from the top was saved via AJAX in the database to each users.
Check for users the table `usermeta`.
Search for item with `meta_key` `metaboxhidden_stiri`.
See the value for this entry. This is a serialiced entry, but you can see, which meta box are hidden on start to edit a post to this CPT.

For example a entry: `a:3:{i:0;s:10:"postcustom";i:1;s:16:"commentstatusdiv";i:2;s:7:"slugdiv";}`

Also give it a `meta_mey` for default closed items: `closedpostboxes_stiri`. Check also this.

Comment: i resolve, it was a plugin error :)